# Facebook Objects API Queries o

Tags: facebook-graph-api, filter

I have asked some old questions previously but those were quite misleading. So I decided to delete them and creating this one.

My object has a custom property named say it is portal content. In the Facebook Graph API Explorer data related to this object shown like;

```
{
  "created_time": "2015-11-26T08:42:26+0000",
  "title": "Title",
  "type": "ns:type",
  "data": {
    "portalcontent": "portalcontent"
  },
  "id": "12515125125"
},
{
  "created_time": "2015-11-26T08:04:09+0000",
  "title": "Title2",
  "type": "ns:type",
  "id": "412512512512"
},
{
  "created_time": "2015-11-25T12:56:03+0000",
  "title": "Title3",
  "type": "ns:type",
  "id": "234124124124"
}
```

I am trying to query this data using Facebook graph api. But can not fetch just based on the portal content custom property.

So far I tried;

```
appid/objects?pretty=0&type=ns:type&limit=100&portalcontent=portalcontent
```

to do so. But it is still fetching all objects.

PS: please pm or comment on question for why you are downvoting it. Provide what else you need that I must put on the question. Downvoting for no reason getting people annoyed.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no way to filter results other than those described on the respective endpoint's docs.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/objects/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5